# :nth-child - Activate on Parent Hover

Tags: css, hover, parent-child, css-selectors

I am looking to hover the parent element and have it change CSS of the all the children. I thought this would be simple. It's easy enough to say:

```
.element:hover .children{
}
```

And on hover that element, you can identify what elements you want to be impacted. I'm looking to have all the children impacted here, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is a quick example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqTcT/11/

And this is the specific nth-child CSS I'm using:

```
.rowYellow:hover .rowYellow:nth-child(n){
    color:yellow;
}
```

I've also tried using what I know works (the first example, where I specific an element to change on hover) and using multiple elements http://jsfiddle.net/ZqTcT/12/:

```
.rowYellow:hover .rowIcon .rowLabel{
    color:yellow;
}
```

I knew I got into the habit of separating statements like that out into two (or more) because it doesn't work either.

So, where am I going wrong? Can either approach work? If so... how?

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.rowYellow:hover .rowYellow:nth-child(n){
```

The above will only affect elements with class `rowYellow` within one with class `rowYellow`.

Instead, to affect all children, just do this with the `*` selector:

```
.rowYellow:hover *{
    color:yellow;
}
```

[**jsFiddle A**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqTcT/13/)

Your second selector says "all elements of class `rowLabel` within elements of class `rowIcon` within hovered elements of class `rowYellow`", which is not what you want. Instead, you want a comma-delimited selector:

```
.rowYellow:hover .rowIcon, .rowYellow:hover .rowLabel{
    color:yellow;
}
```

[**jsFiddle B**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqTcT/15/)

As a side-note, I also recommend [30 CSS selectors you must memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/) as it's very helpful until you've got every selector nailed down well.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about * selector. And what do you mean by "within one class with rowYellow" ? I was under the assumption the .elment:nth-child() effected the children within that element, in this case, it failed because I needed an integer within the (). That's correct, right? So that if going forwarc, I don't want to select all children, but just some, I can make a similar statement and it will be saying, when you have X element, do this to some of the children (whatever is within the () ) of X element.

Comment: The issue with the first one is that, to work "correctly", it should have been [`.rowYellow:hover :nth-child(n){`](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqTcT/16/). The inner children you were trying to select needed to have `rowYellow` class otherwise. And sorry, I was wrong--it takes an integer with `n` (the `1` is implicit).